# JRE не видит модули зависимостей в .jar файле

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Я написал приложение с `JavaFx` в `IntelliJ IDEA` , собрал его в jar встроенным инструментом, и при запуске `jar`, выдает ошибку что не может найти не один модуль зависимости.

Запускаю через cmd:

```
java --module-path "D:\...\MyJar.jar" --module caster/caster.Main
```

И каждый раз выдает ошибки:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer              
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found, required by caster 

java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found, required by caster

java.lang.module.FindException: Module okhttp3 not found, required by caster
```

и тд, ко всем зависимостям

module-info.java

```
open module caster{
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires okhttp3;
requires annotations;
requires java.desktop;                                                                        
}
```

Хотя в jar они есть:

[image: пример]

Что нужно поправить, или `IDEA` неправильно собирает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение [здесь](https://taylorial.com/tools/jar/), а именно:

1. Добавил новый `Main` класс который не наследуется от `Application`
2. Проверил чтобы файлы `javafx` находились в моем `jar`, они были добавлены по умолчанию
3. Запустил как обычный `jar`: `java -jar MyApp.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Ты неправильно написал java команду. Тебе надо было написать `--module-path "путь до специальной для запуска библиотеки java fx\lib"`, а ты указал jar файл. Во вторых метода `--modules` не существует, тебе надо написать `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`, если используешь еще какие-то модули, то добавь их через запятую. Целиком команда должна выглядеть так: `java --module-path "<путь до JavaFX библиотеки>\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar <путь до .jar без кавычек>`. Скачать саму JavaFX библиотеку ты можешь здесь:
https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ просто выбери свою ОС и скачай той же версии java, на которой ты писал и не забудь разархивировать и достать от туда папку.

Comment: А разве JavaFx не должен быть упакован в jar? У меня же есть папка `javafx`

Comment: Нет, не должен. В jar должен быть упакован только java проект, а библиотека - нет

Comment: Ну оказалось что он всё-таки упаковывается, притом по умолчанию, так что я просто запускаю через `-jar`